# Apply for two long-term Schengen visas at a same time

Tags: schengen

I have a job offer from **Country A** and I have applied for a long-term visa before. My application has been rejected and it's in the remonstration process which is taking a long time because of the pandemic.

At the same time, I can apply for a startup long-term visa at **Country B**.

My priority is **Country A** right now but I'm not sure how much time it will take and if it will be successful or not.

The question is, while my remonstration is processing at the **Country A** embassy, can I apply for a D-visa at the embassy of **Country B**? Does it have negative effects on my first application?

***Both countries belong to Schengen area.***

Comment: D-Visas are national visas granting certain rights within one specific country. Thus 2 separate D-Visas may coexist at the same time. For C-Visas, the situation is different, since rights are (in general) granted for all countries within the Schengen Area for which ony one country should be responsible for.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkJohnson So I can apply for both D-Visas without worrying about any effect on each other.